# Hudson - How to configure the number of Jobs in the View-level Build History?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I have a view in my Hudson instance configured with about 300 builds for a given software release. There is a "Build History" link on the left side of the screen, and when I click on it, it lists the 50 most recent jobs built along with a few columns. (Note that I am referring to the Build History for a given view - Not a specific job.)

One of the columns is a status that gives messages, for example "2 more tests are failing". When new tests are failing it also displays the message in red text.

What I am wondering is if it possible to increase the number of jobs that display from 50 to a higher number? Or alternatively is it possible to query these handy status messages elsewhere?
Basically I just want to be able to know the changes in my test status from build to build - when additional tests start failing.

Comment: Consider using [Dashboard View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) more specifically the "Test Statistics Chart" and "Test Statistics Grid". If this is a suitable answer I will make a proper reply in a while...

Comment: I use these already actually. I did find a workaround that was good enough though. By using a build history RSS feed, I was able to see a full readout on the latest build status of the jobs - not limited to 50.